# Memory footprint of tab in chrome going to 1 gb while heap size is 150mb

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, shared-memory, v8, heap-memory

We are working on app , if we leave the app open for weeks
memory footprints of tab went to 1 gb while heap size remains constant.
I want to know what are the components of the memory total and what all makes that memory so its easy to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Everything consumes memory: DOM nodes, images, fonts, WebGL buffers and textures, sound and media files, and so on (I don't claim that this list is exhaustive).

Chances are you have a leak somewhere. Chances are you have some code that runs periodically (maybe refreshing state with `setTimeout` or `setInterval`?) and keeps some reference alive. If by "heap size" you mean the JavaScript heap size, and if it actually remains entirely constant, then I'd look in the direction of DOM nodes that get created in that callback.